# What is the actual instance we get for a Map?

Tags: flutter, dart, hashmap

If I create a `Map` like this

```
Map<String, dynamic> map = Map<String, dynamic>();
```

In Documentation it says, It returns `LinkedHashMap`

```
  /// Creates an empty [LinkedHashMap].
  ///
  /// This constructor is equivalent to the non-const map literal `<K,V>{}`.
  ///
  /// A `LinkedHashMap` requires the keys to implement compatible
  /// `operator==` and `hashCode`.
  /// It iterates in key insertion order.
  external factory Map();
```

And the `LinkedHashMap` also an abstract class, we cannot create object for abstract class in dart.

```
abstract class LinkedHashMap<K, V> implements Map<K, V> {
  /// Creates an insertion-ordered hash-table based [Map].
  ///
```

What is the actual instance we get in `Map` Constructor?
I am using the **dart version 2.16.1 latest stable**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `Map` default constructor is a [factory constructor](https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#factory-constructors) that makes a `LinkedHashMap` using its default constructor. The `LinkedHashMap` default constructor is also a factory constructor, and it makes an object of one of a few internal classes:

- `_InternalLinkedHashMap`
- `_CompactLinkedIdentityHashMap`
- `_CompactLinkedCustomHashMap`

As for which one it chooses, that's based on what kind of `equals`, `hashCode`, and `isValidKey` methods were provided. For your case of calling `Map()`, it's going to be the first one, `_InternalLinkedHashMap`.

### Source code

Here is the latest version (as of today) of the classes and constructors I mentioned:

- constructors: [hash_factories.dart](https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/blob/3dbb3595c8f879b666d8bfdf45106e573fa89eb3/sdk/lib/_internal/vm/lib/hash_factories.dart#L11)
- `_InternalLinkedHashMap`: [compact_hash.dart](https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/blob/6faa5f3bd00ad8cbc640b3fc80cf7466c002a7df/sdk/lib/_internal/vm/lib/compact_hash.dart#L243)
- `_CompactLinkedIdentityHashMap`: [compact_hash.dart](https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/blob/6faa5f3bd00ad8cbc640b3fc80cf7466c002a7df/sdk/lib/_internal/vm/lib/compact_hash.dart#L592)
- `_CompactLinkedCustomHashMap`: [compact_hash.dart](https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/blob/6faa5f3bd00ad8cbc640b3fc80cf7466c002a7df/sdk/lib/_internal/vm/lib/compact_hash.dart#L612)

Comment: Oh Where could I find the internal classes?

Comment: I've updated my answer to link to the source code.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, Its weird that I am using the dart version 2.16.1 latest stable
I can see the `LinkedHashMap` is an abstract class in the library code via androidstudio
But in your link it is implemented as normal class? Did they changed it?

Comment: `LinkedHashMap` is an abstract class.  The actual implemented class might be different between the Dart VM and Dart for the web.

Answer (score -1):

> What is the actual instance we get in Map Constructor?

The answer is   `LinkedHashMap`. It's a concrete class, not an abstract class.

See [LinkedHashMap](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.15.1/dart-collection/LinkedHashMap-class.html).

The other example of the `implementers of Map` is [HashMap](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.15.1/dart-collection/HashMap-class.html).

Comment: `LinkedHashMap` is indeed an abstract class. Note the breadcrumb in [the official documentation](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.15.1/dart-collection/LinkedHashMap-class.html) you linked, which says "LinkedHashMap<K, V> abstract class"